# Running a linux command from Windows .bat

Tags: linux, batch-file

Question:

I want to know if it is possible to write a batch script that will open/run a file located in Linux?

Comment: You need to be clearer. What do you mean by "located in Linux"? Are you talking about a Cygwin shell, a remote Linux machine or a local Linux VM? What exactly are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: located in a Linux VM. I have a file in my Linux VM and I want to run it from my host windows machine via .batch

Comment: Ever heard of putty and all of it other tools like plink.

Answer (score 1):

Put an SSH daemon on your Linux machine.

Set up an SSH key so you can SSH from the Windows machine to the Linux machine.

Install an SSH command line client on your Windows machine. Configure it to use your SSH key.

Call the SSH command line client from your batch script:

```
<ssh_client> <user>@<machine> <command
```

e.g.

```
ssh me@my_server my_script.sh arg1 arg2
```